# All combinations of items in N arrays in C#

Tags: c#, linq, combinatorics

I can have N arrays of different length.
Important thing is that I dont know how many arrays I can have.
Let's we have 3 arrays:

```
arr1: { obj11, obj12, obj13, ...., obj1J }  
arr2: { obj21, obj22, obj23, .........., obj2K }  
arr3: { obj31, obj32, obj33, ................, obj3L }
```

How can I produce combinations of each item with each other like this:

```
1.  [obj11, obj21, obj31]  
2.  [obj11, obj21, obj32]  
..  
L.  [obj11, obj21, obj 3L]  
L+1.[obj11, obj22, obj 31]  
....
```

Talking about C# implementation (maybe Linq?)

Comment: So you just want those 3 elements of each array?

Comment: Yes, each combination will have number of items equal to the number of arrays.